# PIL Image doesnt see the local file in the same directory

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pystray

```
import pystray
from PIL import Image
from importlib import reload
import os
import webbrowser

# Image for the tray
image = Image.open("image.png")

# Triggers for right click
def stop(icon, item):
    icon.stop()

def ss(icon, item):
    import discord

def edit(icon, item):
    os.system('config.json')

def git(icon, item):
    webbrowser.open('github')

def support(icon, item):
    webbrowser.open('discord')

# Buttons for right click
icon = pystray.Icon("Hydisc", image, menu=pystray.Menu(
    pystray.MenuItem("Start", ss),
    pystray.MenuItem("Edit Settings", edit),
    pystray.MenuItem("Github", git),
    pystray.MenuItem("Support", support),
    pystray.MenuItem("Quit", stop)
))

icon.run()
```

Files: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tORxl.png

I have image.png and tray.py in the same menu but when i run it PIL Image cant find the file heres the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXwIE.png

Comment: _I have image.png and tray.py in the same menu_ That doesn't matter.  It's looking in the **current** directory, which is not necessarily the same.

Comment: @JohnGordon Sorry, i worded that wrong they are both in the same directory

Comment: I understood what you meant.  It does not matter that they are in the same directory.  The "current directory" is NOT necessarily the same directory where the python script is located.

Comment: If you need it relative to the file you can do `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), name)`